# How to use fax with my VoIP

Tags: voip

Well the site seems to be Hide Park for networking experts. To be honest I am not any expert at all. I followed my friend have recently got a business plan (for my new business) from [Axvoice](http://www.axvoice.com) because of its low rates. They don’t provide or support fax officially. In a few forums, I have read people are making a few modifications and using Fax with Axvoice. I posted in many forums how people were using fax with Axvoice but no one replied. My questions are

1 : - Is it possible at all to use fax with Axvoice or I am having a wild goose chase?

2 : - If it is possible, can I being a non-technical person do it at my own?

3 : - I will be thankful if anyone can note down the procedure or give any link that could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Fax over VOIP requires that the provider either supports uncompressed audio codecs like G.711, and/or more specifically T.38 (which is designed for VOIP).

If I were you, I'd avoid Fax over VOIP, it's not particularly reliable. There are other options, [email to fax gateways](https://www.google.com/search?q=email%20to%20fax%20gateways) for example, which are much more reliable, and are usually less susceptible to problems with lag and bandwidth that SOHO connections often experience (and it's the lag and bandwidth which cause the most problems).